# lineno and syntax package incompatibilities

Tags: incompatibility, syntax, line-numbering, grammar

I'm using the syntax package from the mdwtools version 1996/05/17 1.07. I 
successfully set the properties to show a grammar definition properly but then 
when I try to combine it with the lineno package I got a nasty error showing a 
double line number for each new rule. Then digging the code of syntax.sty I 
found I can fix the problem in the definition of 'grammar' commenting this line:

```
\vskip-\baselineskip%
```

Now it works better but I have extra new lines between rules. In fact the 
definitions start at line number 2 and I cannot remove these extra lines! (It seems is related to the lists command) I suppose this is a bug. TeX is far out from my expertize so I report this bug wondering if someone have a workaround or help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx, please provide a minimal working example of a document that we could compile that illustrates this error: this helps understand what the problem is, and possibly, how to fix it.

Comment: See here for details of what an MWE is: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/215

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{lineno}

\makeatletter
\def\gr@implitem<#1> #2 {%
 \sbox\z@{\hskip\labelsep\grammarlabel{#1}{#2}}%
  \strut\@@@par% lineno.sty redefines \@@par which was in the original code
 \vspace{-\parskip}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \hrule\@height\z@\@depth\z@\relax%
  \item[\unhbox\z@]%
  \catcode`\<\active%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers}
\begin{grammar}

<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr> 
\alt ‘for’ <ident> ‘=’ <expr> ‘to’ <expr> ‘do’ <statement> 
\alt ‘{’ <stat-list> ‘}’ 
\alt <empty> 
<stat-list> ::= <statement> ‘;’ <stat-list> | <statement> 

<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr> 
\alt ‘for’ <ident> ‘=’ <expr> ‘to’ <expr> ‘do’ <statement> 
\alt ‘{’ <stat-list> ‘}’ 
\alt <empty> 

\end{grammar} 
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: `lineno.sty` counts lines based on the `\par` macro which is internally in LaTeX `\@@par`.  lineno.sty needs to use its own version of that, `\@@@par` which keeps track of spurious blank lines. Replacing `syntax.sty` use of  `\@@par` with `\@@@par` fixes the problem.

Comment: Great! This solves the problem. Now I just need to change the space between definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use one paclage like `listings` for example ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

<statement> ::= <ident> = <expr> 
  |  for <ident> = <expr> to <expr> do <statement> 
  |    <stat-list>
  |  <empty> 
<stat-list> ::= <statement> ; <stat-list> | <statement> 

<statement> ::= <ident> = <expr> 
  |  for <ident> = <expr> to <expr> do <statement> 
  |    <stat-list>
  |  <empty> 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although `listings` could be made to emulate the `syntax` package fairly easily, out of the box your example doesn't format the grammar very nicely compared to the `syntax` package. You also forgot to number the lines in your example, which was the point of the question. Can `listings` ignore blank lines in its numbering system?